# SQL LOADER CONTROL FILE

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader, controlfile

I have this loader control file.

```
LOAD DATA
REPLACE
INTO TABLE TEST
WHEN TEST_CD != 'A' AND TEST_CD = 'B' AND TEST_TYPE_CD = 15
```

Currently its loading data when TEST_CD = 'B' AND TEST_TYPE_CD = 15 but now I want to modify it so that when TEST_CD = 'B' as well as test_type_cd = 15 too.. I dont want to load all Test_type_cd when its 15.. i want to load only when it satisfies both condition.. Just keeping the braces around it is going to work.. Plz some one let me know how can I modify this..

I am thinking everyone is confused with what I need.. I want first condition to satisfy as well as 2nd and 3rd condition as 1 condition not to act seperately.. For example if test_cd is not equal A than load the data but 2nd and 3rd condition should act as one piece..when test_cd = B and test_type_cd is 15 than load the data.. i dont want test_type_cd to apply for any other test_cd other than B.. I have 5 of those test_cd A B C D E.. i want only B to apply test_type_cd = 15..

Comment: You mean you want to load data either TEST_CD = 'B' or TEST_TYPE_CD =5 or both?

Comment: Your code already makes makes sure both conditions are satisfied.

Comment: i want to load data when test_cd = 'B' and for that row if test_type_cdis 15 too.. when it satisfy both conditions.. right now it doesnt care when test_cd is b test type cd is 15 or not.. if it satisfies one its loading

Comment: Also, having `TEST_CD != 'A'` is unnecessary because of `TEST_CD = 'B'`.

Comment: Can you double check that something else isn't broken?  Because your syntax is correct.  You're already using an `AND` operator not an `OR` operator so it's impossible for it to behave the way you have described.

Comment: wants to apply test_type_cd = 15 only to test_cd B.. i dont want to apply it to other test_cd C D E that i have

Comment: OR is not an option in SQL loader

Comment: Jack, thanks for the clarification.  +1 for niktrs solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
LOAD DATA
REPLACE
INTO TABLE TEST
WHEN TEST_CD = 'B' AND TEST_TYPE_CD = 15 -- load everything that is b and 15
INTO TABLE TEST
WHEN TEST_CD != 'A' AND TEST_CD != B -- load everything that is not a and not b (because it is loaded above)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you want it to load in when EITHER condition is true, not necessarily BOTH conditions?

```
WHEN TEST_CD != 'A' AND (TEST_CD = 'B' OR TEST_TYPE_CD = 15)
```

may satisfy the fractured English of your initial question.